# Directory list for FOR loop in msdos .bat file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, directory, dos

I am looking how to get list of all directories to be used in FOR loop.

So far I have work around:

```
set folderList = (folder1 folder2 folder3 folder4)
FOR %%i in %folderList% do zip %%i D:\...my_path...\%%i\*.*
```

is it possible that folderList would be generated dynamically ?

Comment: Is folder1 folder2 folder3 folder on the same directory? E.g. all folders are located in C:\

Answer (score 6):

assuming you want to list subdirectories of c:\temp

```
for /f %%i in ('dir c:\temp /ad /b') do echo %%i
```

this will list foldernames of c:\temp, if you want get it recursively just add /s to dir command:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir c:\temp /ad /b /s') do echo %%i
```

as for @dbenham comment (thank you)  to correctly handle dirs with space just add tokens=* to for :

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir c:\temp /ad /b') do echo %%i
```

Comment: The solutions you posted will not work as written if a folder name contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code:

```
for /d %%F in ("d:\...my_path...\*") do zip "%%~nxF" "%%F\*.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is different but the double %% listed above are all failing to work.

This, however, works for me:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir c:\temp /ad /b') do echo %I
```